# echo $! after starting process no PID

Tags: pidfile

I have an init script that executes a jar file in the background, and I want to print the PID to a file. Using the following immediately after the execute command the file is created, but it is empty.

```
start process & \
echo $! >/var/run/foo.pid
```

Why might this be?
Thanks

Comment: Your question title says ```$1``` but your question body says ```$!```. Which is it?

Comment: Which shell is used to execute the "init script"?

Comment: 1) what user runs the script? 2) does it work if you run the script as that user, but from the command line? 3) is something else truncating the file? 4) did the `start process` thing actually run or did you get a "no such file or directory" error? (i.e. is `PATH` correctly set in the script?)

Comment: Title had typo, I've corrected that.

Comment: Using Bash shell, script being run as root, but jar file being executed as AD generic account specified in script, jar file runs as expected with no error printed, path is correct as the file is successfully created but blank.